# Acumatica - BQL Query with three "ands"

Tags: acumatica

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my BQL query? It is bleeding in VS everywhere. Don't understand why the devs at Acumatica decided to go with such an awkward query language.

```
                var oldRec = PXSelectReadonly<SOLine, 
                                    Where<SOLine.orderType, Equal<Required<SOLine.origOrderType>>, 
                                    And<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOLine.origOrderNbr>>, 
                                    And<SOLine.lineNbr, Equal<Required<SOLine.origLineNbr>>>>>.Select(Base, orderLine.OrigOrderType, orderLine.OrigOrderNbr, orderLine.OrigLineNbr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you're missing a closing bracket '>' at the end.

In any case this should be pretty bulletproof syntax wise:

```
PX.Objects.SO.SOLine orderLine = new PX.Objects.SO.SOLine();

var oldRec = PXSelectReadonly<PX.Objects.SO.SOLine,
                Where<PX.Objects.SO.SOLine.orderType, Equal<Required<PX.Objects.SO.SOLine.origOrderType>>, 
                And<PX.Objects.SO.SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<PX.Objects.SO.SOLine.origOrderNbr>>, 
                And<PX.Objects.SO.SOLine.lineNbr, Equal<Required<PX.Objects.SO.SOLine.origLineNbr>>>>>>.Select(Base, orderLine.OrigOrderType, orderLine.OrigOrderNbr, orderLine.OrigLineNbr);
```

When used in a graph extension 'PXGraphExtension' you specify 'Base' as the first parameter, as you did. Base refers to the base graph, you use 'Base' because the first parameter type is PXGraph instead of PXGraphExtension.

When used in a graph 'PXGraph' you use 'this' instead of base.

Comment: Yeah this is a customization I am developing. Thanks for the answer.